# Kentico 13 IPageRetriever not taking in OrderBy and FirstOrDefault clauses in Query

Tags: kentico, kentico-13

I'm using the `IPageRetriever` but am having issues with some of the `queryParametersAction`

```
var retriever = await _pageRetriever.RetrieveAsync<News>(
    query =>
    {
        query
        .PathForChildren(path)
        .NestingLevel(depth)
        .Columns(new string[] {
            nameof(News.NodeAliasPath),
            nameof(News.ListableDocumentImage),
            nameof(News.ListableDocumentImageAlt),
            nameof(News.ListableDocumentTitle),
            nameof(News.ListableDocumentRollupText),
            nameof(News.OccurrenceDate),
            nameof(News.BaseContent),
            nameof(News.FeaturedContent),
        })
        .WhereTrue(nameof(News.FeaturedContent)) //works
        //.Where(n => n.FeaturedContent == true) //doesn't work
        .OrderByDescending(n => n.OccurrenceDate) //doesn't work
        .FirstOrDefault(); //doesn't work
 
    },
            cacheSettings => cacheSettings
        .Dependencies((items, csbuilder) => builder.ApplyDependenciesTo(key => csbuilder.Custom(key)))
        .Key($"GetFeaturedItemAsync|{path}|{depth}")
        .Expiration(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Constants.CACHE_MINUTES))
    );
```

These work using `new DocumentQuery()` and PageRetriever uses DocumentQuery and the [documentation link](https://docs.xperience.io/custom-development/working-with-pages-in-the-api) to the available params includes all these methods.

Am I getting the order wrong? When I call query.ToString(true) to see the Sql query from it, there is no mention of the above methods in the sql query.

Granted, the documentation does say:

> IPageRetriever (Kentico.Content.Web.Mvc namespace) – interface that
> provides a service for retrieving pages in basic live site scenarios

But have no definition for what basic means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up some Linq statements and Kentico query statements.

The where clausule can be used with a lot of different conditions, for example you can use `.WhereEquals(nameof(News.FeaturedContent), true)`

For the OrderByDescending you should use a string parameter. So that would be `.OrderByDescending(nameof(News.OccurrenceDate))`.

For the FirstOrDefault you can use `.TopN(1)` for the query and then you need to use `.FirstOrDefault()` after the `RetrieveAsync` method as the Linq method can't be added to the query that Kentico creates.